# Inner Join in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_All_Items]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ItemID, ItemName, CategoryID, CountryID,
        ItemSize, ColorID, ProductionDate, ExpiryDate, 
        UnitName, FirstUnitBarcode, FirstItemQuantity, 
        FirstUnitDefult, FirstUnitLimit, 
        UnitsTbl.SecondUnit, SecondUnitBarcode, SecondItemQuantity, 
        SecondUnitDefult, SecondUnitLimit, 
        ThirdUnit, ThirdUnitBarcode, ThirdItemQuantity, 
        ThirdUnitDefult, ThirdUnitLimit, UnitDefult, 
        ItemImage, ItemStatus, ItemsMainTbl.Nots,
        ItemsMainTbl.CreatedBy, ItemsMainTbl.CreatedDate, 
        ItemsMainTbl.ModifiedBy, ItemsMainTbl.ModifiedDate 
    FROM 
        ItemsMainTbl  
    INNER JOIN
        UnitsTbl ON ItemsMainTbl.FirstUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID 
    INNER JOIN
        UnitsTbl ON ItemsMainTbl.SecondUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID 
END
```

Conditions:

- ItemsMainTbl.FirstUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID
- ItemsMainTbl.SecondUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID
- ItemsMainTbl.ThirdUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID

How to join all three tables on that common column?

I got only the first one

```
ItemsMainTbl.FirstUnit = UnitsTbl.UnitID
```

Thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with VB.NET and nothing to do with Visual Studio. In future please use the right tags.

Comment: Salem, describe fields in your tables. It's impossible to understand ` Iam Not Getting This UnitName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define reference for you UnitsTbl. Think of these references as new objects of same class, in terms of OOP. Also, it is a good habit to use references for whenever querying over a table.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    ItemsMainTbl t1
INNER JOIN
    UnitsTbl u1 ON t1.FirstUnit = u1.UnitID 
INNER JOIN
    UnitsTbl u2 ON t1.SecondUnit = u2.UnitID 
INNER JOIN 
    UnitsTbl u3 ON t1.ThirdUnit = u3.UnitID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join the same table multiple times, you need to specify an alias for each instance of the joined table, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemsMainTbl  
INNER JOIN UnitsTbl u1 ON ItemsMainTbl.FirstUnit = u1.UnitID 
INNER JOIN UnitsTbl u2 ON ItemsMainTbl.SecondUnit = u2.UnitID 
INNER JOIN UnitsTbl u3 ON ItemsMainTbl.ThirdUnit = u3.UnitID
```

Then in the select statement, you can differentiate between the joined instances, like this:

```
SELECT u1.Barcode, -- Barcode from FirstUnit
       u2.Barcode, -- Barcode from SecondUnit
       u3.Barcode  -- Barcode from ThirdUnit
```

Comment: Why `INNER JOIN` became `LEFT OUTER` ??

Comment: Oops! Didn't mean to change the join type. Post edited.